# Problema al guardar datos en matriz dinamica en C

Tags: array, c, funciones, punteros

El programa es una funcion recursiva que guarda en una matriz dinamica todas las posibles combinaciones de un numero expresado como suma de cubos **`(n = a^3 + b^3)`**.

Dentro del procedimiento veo lo que escribe y creo que es la direccion de memoria en vez de los datos.

> La matriz la inicialicé así: `int **matriz = NULL;`.
>   Se inicializan en cero (0): `i, j y fila`.

```
void suma_de_cubos(int **v, int n, int i, int j, int fila){
    printf("VAMOS POR A = %i , B = %i\n",i,j);
    if (pow(i,3) > n){

        puts("De momento no hagas nada paiaso");

    }else{

        if (pow(i,3) + pow(j,3) < n){

            suma_de_cubos(v,n,i,j+1,fila);
            puts("_________Estoy en el <_________");
        }else{
            if (pow(i,3) + pow(j,3) == n){
                puts("___##____Estoy en el =____##___");
                v = (int **)malloc((fila+1)*sizeof(int *));
                puts("Primer malloc guay");
                if(v == NULL) puts("Tenemos un problema con la matriz");
                (v)[fila] = (int *)malloc(3*sizeof(int));
                puts("Segundo malloc guay");
                puts("antes");
                printf(" %i ",v[fila][0]);
                printf(" %i ",v[fila][1]);
                puts("");
                (v)[fila][0] = i;
                (v)[fila][1] = j;
                puts("despues");
                printf(" %i ",v[fila][0]);
                printf(" %i ",v[fila][1]);
                puts("");
                suma_de_cubos(v,n,i+1,i+1,fila+1);

            }else suma_de_cubos(v,n,i+1,i+1,fila);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ¿Y qué problema tienes exactamente? ¿No compila? ¿No hace lo que esperas? ¿Funciona bien pero no sabes cómo continuar?

Comment: He hecho algunas pruebas y por lo que veo dentro de la funcion si que "guarda los datos" luego en el compruebo si es null if(v == NULL) puts("Tenemos un problema con la matriz"); y me da positivo, como si no se hubiese guardado

Answer (score 0):

Ya lo pude resolver, si paso la direccion de manera que el procedimiento pida int ***v lo guarda bien, pensé que no hacia falta ya que al pasar un vector o array tenia entendido que se pasaba la dirección del mismo.

El código quedaría así:

```
void suma_de_cubos(int ***v, int n, int i, int j, int fila){
    if (pow(i,3) > n){

        escribir_matriz(v,fila); //escribe matriz en pantalla

    }else{

        if (pow(i,3) + pow(j,3) < n){

            suma_de_cubos(v,n,i,j+1,fila);

        }else{
            if (pow(i,3) + pow(j,3) == n){

                *v = (int **)realloc(*v,(fila+1)*sizeof(int *));

                if(*v == NULL) puts("Tenemos un problema con la matriz");
                (*v)[fila] = (int *)malloc(2*sizeof(int));

                (*v)[fila][0] = i;
                (*v)[fila][1] = j;

                suma_de_cubos(v,n,i+1,i+1,fila+1);

            }else suma_de_cubos(v,n,i+1,i+1,fila);
        }
    }
}
```